# PHP Logout 500 error

Tags: php, html, error-handling

I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error on execution of my logout script. Checked the error log and found this.

ERROR IS:

> ../../logout.php is writeable by group. refer: ../../user-dashboard.php

logout.php code is

```
<?php       

require_once('session.php');
require_once('class.user.php');
$user_logout = new USER();

if($user_logout->is_loggedin()!="")
{
    $user_logout->redirect('user-dashboard.php');
}
if(isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout']=="true")
{
    $user_logout->doLogout();
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo "if (window.confirm('Successfully Logged Out ! ')) 
            {
                window.location.href='login.php';
            };";            
    echo '</script>';
}

?>
```

user-dashboard.php

```
<?php

require_once("session.php");
require_once("class.user.php");
$auth_user = new USER();


$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];

$stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM user_credentials WHERE user_id=:user_id");
$stmt->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));

$userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
```

Can't seem to figure out the error from these codes. Kind assist would be well appreciated. The script works perfectly on XAMPP when testing but throws the error on a live server.

Comment: `chmod 644 logout.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I Simply changed the permission code to 644